# Access linkedin SSI using rest api?

Tags: python, rest, linkedin-api

I have the rest of the API working with full profile access. But is there any way to access the Social selling index field?

Code so far is attached below. Just need the field name for the SSI for the last session.get statement.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix

# In case the `redirect_url` does not implement https     
import os                                                   

# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = ''
client_secret = ''
redirect_url = ''

# OAuth endpoints given in the LinkedIn API documentation (check for updates)
authorize_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

session = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_url)
session = linkedin_compliance_fix(session)
# Authorized Redirect URL (from LinkedIn config)
uri, state = session.authorization_url(authorize_url)

print('Please go here and authorize,', uri)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')
# Fetch the access token
token = session.fetch_token(token_url,authorization_response=redirect_response,client_secret=client_secret)
print(token)
# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = session.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(<what do i put here>)?format=json')
print(r.content)
```